# Delete sql statement not working - trying to delete a recipe using the recipe_id

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

Creating a `DELETE` function.
I am deleting a recipe based off of its `recipe_id`, unique `indicator`.

Problem I noticed, whenever i send the request `handleDelete` to my `backend`, the `recipe_id` is *empty* - of course this means I won't be able to `delete` the recipe.

I tried `loggin` a variety of things, in order to understand what I am doing wrong and where I am going wrong. Didn't find anything so far.

**Profile.js__**

```
    handleDelete(recipe) {
        const jwt = localStorage.getItem("jwt");
        axios({
          method: "delete",
          data: {
            recipe_id: this.state.recipe_id
          },
          url: "http://localhost:4000/api/recipe",
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + jwt
          }
        })
          .then(response => {
            this.setState({ recipe: response.data.recipe });
          })
          .catch((error, res) => {
            if (error.response.status === 401) {
              console.log("Error:", error);
            }
          });
      }
```

**api/index.js__**

```
    api.delete('/recipe', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), (req, res) => {
        const recipe_id = req.body.recipe_id

          db.query('DELETE FROM recipes WHERE recipe_id = ?', 
          [req.body.recipe_id], (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log("Err:", err)
          res.status(500)
          return;
        }
        db.query('SELECT * FROM recipes', (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500)
          return;
            }
        res.json({recipes: rows});
    })
    })
    });
```

Yes the indentation sucks, copy paste's fault.

**All the relevant code can be found here:** https://gist.github.com/MisterSemaan/07d7cf52b0069d2ea89b29f608c2b976

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are handling everything regarding state correct. Then I would suggest to change Profile.js class to have different rendering (I don't think that Profile component should know how to split Recipe for RecipeCard)

**Profile.js**

```js
  <RecipeCard
     className="recipeCard"
     recipe={data}
     handleDelete={this.handleDelete.bind(this)}
  />
```

and of course keep the change regarding handleDelete function:

```js
 handleDelete(recipe) {
    const jwt = localStorage.getItem("jwt");
    console.log(jwt);
    axios({
      method: "delete",
      data: {
        recipe_id: recipe.recipe_id
      },
      url: "http://localhost:4000/api/recipe",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + jwt
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.status === 200) {
          console.log("Delete Success");
          window.location.reload();
        }
        this.setState({ recipe: response.data.recipe });
      })
      .catch((error, res) => {
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
          console.log("Error:", error);
          alert("Failed");
        }
      });
  }
```

Then in RecipeCard.js try to benefit from having full recipe in place

**RecipeCard.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';

export default class RecipeCard extends React.Component {

  handleUpdate(){
    if(this.props.handleUpdate){
      this.props.handleUpdate(this.props.recipe)
    }
  }
  handleDelete(){
    if(this.props.handleDelete){
      this.props.handleDelete(this.props.recipe)
    }
  }

 render(){
   const { className, recipe, onClick, image, alt } = this.props
   const { recipe_name, recipe_author, recipe_meal, recipe_description, recipe_ingredients, recipe_preparation} = recipe
  return(
    <div onClick={onClick} className={className}>
      <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom> Name: {recipe_name} </Typography>
      <Typography variant="body1" gutterBottom> Author: {recipe_author} </Typography>
      <Typography variant="body1" gutterBottom> Meal: {recipe_meal} </Typography>
      <Typography variant="body1" gutterBottom> Description: {recipe_description} </Typography>
      <Typography variant="body1" gutterBottom> Ingredients: {recipe_ingredients} </Typography>
      <Typography variant="body1" gutterBottom> Preparation: {recipe_preparation} </Typography>
      <img src={image} alt={alt}/>
      <Button color="primary" variant="contained" onClick={(event) => this.handleDelete(event)}>Delete</Button>
    </div>
  )
 }
}
```

PS. If you are not going to have different classNames for RecipeCard component I would rather embedded it inside RecipeCard and not passing it from Profile

Comment: Thank you sooooo much!
Also thanks for the friendly advice :)

Comment: Your welcome ;) If you are building the ui in react don't make the parent components too smart about how they render the children. If you can defer deciding how it should be rendered to child component do it. Additionally if you are using state try to make it consistent. I would rather prefer to make it more verbose (f.e. make a structure for new recipe a full object in state that you could then sent simply like : ```data: this.state.newRecipe``` instead of make the whole request) and I think you don't use recipes in code